# Can NSFetchedResultsController work with NSDictionaryResultType?

Tags: ios, cocoa, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I use Core Data to store shops as `Entity` Shop  and on every shop I have an `Attribute` city, I want to group the shops by city and present a `UITableView` with all the cities. I use `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch the data and refresh the `UITableView` and since I want to group the cities I set the  `resultType` of the request as `NSDictionaryResultType`. 
However now when I use `objectAtIndexPath` at my `NSFetchedResultsController` I am getting `NSKnownkeysdictionary1`  My question is can I make the `NSFetchedResultsController` handle the `NSDictionaryResultType`or I should drop the use of `NSFetchedResultsController` in this case and take some other approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the NSExpressionDescription for it to fetch the appropriate value. You could do it like this,

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController
{
    if (!_fetchedResultsController) {
        NSExpression *cityKeypath = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"identifier"];
        NSExpressionDescription *cityDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
        cityDescription.expression = cityKeypath;
        cityDescription.name = @"City";
        cityDescription.expressionResultType = NSStringAttributeType;


        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Shop"];
        [fetchRequest setPropertiesToFetch:@[cityDescription]];
        [fetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:@[@"city"]];
        [fetchRequest setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"city" ascending:YES]];
        _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];

       _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
        NSError *error;

        [_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];
    }
    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

So, you need to provide NSExpressionDescription for the properties you want to fetch. The NSFetchedResultsController result will in in dictionary type like this,

```
 {
   @"city": "Kansas"
  }
 ...
```

Comment: It seems like it is going to work, but how do I access the dictionary for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ? It seems like both `objectAtIndexPath` and `fetchedObjects` from `NSFetchedResultsController` can't really do it

Comment: Fetched objects should give you the array of dictionaries.